# Cannot lower brightness in Ubuntu 14.04 with amd drivers

Tags: ati, 14.04, brightness, msi

So I cannot adjust my brightness at all.  It is always at the max and I have tried updating the grub with `acpi_osi=linux` & `acpi_backlight=vendor` & `acpi_osi=` & `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor`.  Whenever I use the vendor the brightness bar just disappears from bightness and lock panel and I cannot use brightness key to get the bar. I'm not sure what I should do to fix this.  I have also reinstalled my video drivers from amd.  But have had no luck.

Comment: Did you make sure to use "sudo update-grub"? (Sometimes people forget) Also some people have success when reinstalling bash (sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash) and make sure to reboot.

Comment: Yes, I made to sure to do it after each one.